# Python decorator with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I have a class with a lot of very similar properties:

```
class myClass(object):

    def compute_foo(self):
        return 3

    def compute_bar(self):
        return 4

    @property
    def foo(self):
        try:
            return self._foo
        except AttributeError:
            self._foo = self.compute_foo()
            return self._foo

    @property
    def bar(self):
        try:
            return self._bar
        except AttributeError:
            self._bar = self.compute_bar()
            return self._bar
    ...
```

So thought I would write a decorator to do the property definition work.

```
class myDecorator(property):
    def __init__(self, func, prop_name):
        self.func = func
        self.prop_name = prop_name
        self.internal_prop_name = '_' + prop_name

    def fget(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)
        except AttributeError:
            obj.__setattr__(self.internal_prop_name, self.func(obj))
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.func is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)


class myClass(object):

    def compute_foo(self):
        return 3
    foo = myDecorator(compute_foo, 'foo')

    def compute_bar(self):
        return 4
    bar = myDecorator(compute_bar, 'bar')
```

This works well, but when I want to use the `@myDecorator('foo')` syntax, it gets more complicated and cannot figure what the `__call__` method should return and how to attach the property to its class.

For the moment I have :

```
class myDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, prop_name):
        self.prop_name = prop_name
        self.internal_prop_name = '_' + prop_name

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        return #???

    def fget(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)
        except AttributeError:
            obj.__setattr__(self.internal_prop_name, self.func(obj))
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.func is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

class myClass(object):
    @myDecorator('foo')
    def compute_foo(self):
        return 3

c = myClass()
print(c.foo)
```

and it returns: `AttributeError: 'myClass' object has no attribute 'foo'`

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I believe what I am trying to achieve is insane... Can `myDecorator` have a idea of what `myClass` is to add a property to it ?

Comment: Not until `__get__()` et alia are invoked.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, there is no point in using the `@myDecorator('foo')` syntax in this case then. The class attribute `foo` should be defined in the class definition and the `myDecorator` should be called `myCustomProperty` ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass a decorated function as an argument to the decorator. This can be solved by using a wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a metaclass, to make the subclassing easier. Thanks to Brendan Abel for hinting in this direction.

```
import types

class PropertyFromCompute(property):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = None
        self.func_name = func.__name__
        self.internal_prop_name = self.func_name.replace('compute', '')

    def fget(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)
        except AttributeError:
            obj.__setattr__(self.internal_prop_name, self.func())
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.func is None:
            try:
                self.func =  obj.__getattribute__(self.func_name)
            except AttributeError:
                raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

class WithPropertyfromCompute(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        add_prop = {}
        for name, obj in dct.items():
            if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType) and name.startswith('compute_'):
                add_prop.update({name.replace('compute_',''): PropertyFromCompute(obj)})
        dct.update(add_prop)
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)


class myClass(object, metaclass=WithPropertyfromCompute):

    def compute_foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Do not instantiate the base class, ever !')

class myChildClass(myClass):

    def compute_foo(self):
        return 4

base = myClass()
try:
    print(base.foo)
except NotImplementedError as e:
    print(e)
print(myClass.foo)
child = myChildClass()
print(child.foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use the wraps trick to pass arguments to your decorator as follows:

```
from functools import wraps

class myDecorator(property):
    def __init__(self, prop_name):
        self.prop_name = prop_name

    def __call__(self, wrappedCall):
        @wraps(wrappedCall)
        def wrapCall(*args, **kwargs):
            klass = args[0]
            result = wrappedCall(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(klass, self.prop_name, result)
        return wrapCall

class myClass(object):
    @myDecorator('foo')
    def compute_foo(self):
        return 3

c = myClass()
c.compute_foo()
print c.foo
```

Comment: Thanks I thought of something like this but I am not familiar with `functools.wraps`. I will have a look into this as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `@decorator` syntax you're not going to be able to remap the property to a different name on the class.  That means your `compute_x` methods are going to have to be renamed the same as the attribute.

EDIT: It is possible to remap the names, but you'd need to use a class decorator as well.

```
class MyProperty(property):
    def __init__(self, name, func):
        super(MyProperty, self).__init__(func)
        self.name = name
        self.internal_prop_name = '_' + name
        self.func = func

    def fget(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)
        except AttributeError:
            obj.__setattr__(self.internal_prop_name, self.func(obj))
            return obj.__getattribute__(self.internal_prop_name)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None)
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.func is None:
            raise AttributeError('unreadable')
        return self.fget(obj)

def myproperty(*args)
    name = None
    def deco(func):
        return MyProperty(name, func)

    if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
        name = args[0].__name__
        return deco(args[0])
    else:
        name = args[0]
        return deco


class Test(object):

    @myproperty
    def foo(self):
        return 5
```

Without the class decorator, the only time the name argument would be relevant would be if your internal variable name was different from the function name, so you could so something like

```
@myproperty('foobar')
def foo(self):
    return 5
```

and it would look for `_foobar` instead of `_foo`, but the attribute name would still be `foo`.

However, there **is** a way you could remap the attribute names, but you'd have to use a class decorator as well.

```
def clsdeco(cls):
    for k, v in cls.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(v, MyProperty) and v.name != k:
            delattr(cls, k)
            setattr(cls, v.name, v)
    return cls


@clsdeco
class Test(...)

    @myproperty('foo')
    def compute_foo(self):
        pass
```

This will go through all the attributes on the class and find any that are `MyProperty` instances and check if the set name is the same as the mapped name, if not, it will rebind the property to the name passed into the `myproperty` decorator.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for the example. I actually have `compute_foo` as a separate function in order to be able to override it when subclassing. So I will probably stick to defining the class attribute separately.

Comment: I like the idea of the class decorator. That's very bright ! I presume I would need to apply the same decorator to all subclasses of Test for it to work ?

Comment: Yes, it would need to be on all subclasses.  You could avoid putting in on all subclasses if you used a metaclass instead of a class decorator.